# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'svntools'

Tags: python

I am new to Python and when I run a Python script it gives me following error.

```
   import svntools.svntools
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'svntools'
```

Can anybody help me to resolve this?

My script is like,

```
import svntools.svntools
from svntools.svntools import *
import svntools.commontools
from svntools.commontools import *
```

When running

```
D:\>pip install svntools
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement svntools (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for svntools
```

Comment: Do you have this ```svntools``` module installed?  Are you running the script using the same python binary as the environment that has the ```svntools``` module installed under?

Comment: No @ewokx, I tried to install as follows, but it didn't work. pip install svntools

Comment: you should make sure the package svntools installed in you python env  or svntools is in you develop path.

Comment: Hi @XiaominWu, Can please you guide me how to install svntools?

Comment: I found no package name svntools on pypi.

Comment: If installing svntools didn't work, how do you expect your script to run?  What happens when you ran ```pip install svntools```?  Please include that in your post.

Comment: As mentioned, that module does not exist in the Python package repository... Therefore, we can't possibly know where it exists, either. You need to tell us where you've got this code, and ask the person that provided it to you... For example, maybe there is a literal `svntools.py` file you're missing

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer, I downloaded this script from pvcs2svn_0_2_20.zip  which is used to migrating PVCS version files to SVN. This was developd by a company called 'Polarion'.

Comment: Since `svntools` is not a PyPi package, either the code you downloaded is broken (perhaps the `svntools` pcakage did exist when it was written?), or `svntools` was a local library that the author did not upload, or they did but you did not properly download it.

Comment: If it's the 3rd case, you can check if you downloaded the code properly, or you can share where you got the code from (e.g. github?) so that we could help you. If it's the other two cases, I'm afraid there's nothing you can do.